# How to prevent .NET optimizer from reasoning over specific values in unit tests?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, optimization

I've been stepping through some of my unit tests in Release builds and discovering that they have a bit *too* much optimization.

For example. I write something like this ...

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test_ToZeroOrOne() {
   UInt64 ul;
   ul = 0UL.ToZeroOrOne();
   Assert.AreEqual(0UL, ul);
   ul = 1234UL.ToZeroOrOne();
   Assert.AreEqual(1UL, ul);
}
```

... to test a function I've written to convert non-zero values to 1 while leaving 0 equal to 0. Essentially converting BOOL to Boolean. Doesn't matter.

Then I step into this test and go read the disassembly and discover that my function has entirely disappeared. There's just calls to `Assert.AreEqual(0, 0);` and then `Assert.AreEqual(1, 1);` Which in hindsight makes perfect sense. And *maybe* is correct. But it seemed somehow unsatisfying.

So I came up with this ...

```
static Int64 g_deoptimize = 0;
const Int64 c_deoptimize_never = Int64.MaxValue - 42;

public static UInt64 Deoptimize(this UInt64 ul) {
   g_deoptimize += (ul%2 == 0) ? 1 : -1;
   if (g_deoptimize == c_deoptimize_never) {
      ul++;
   }
   return ul;
}

public static void AfterDeoptimize() {
   if (g_deoptimize == c_deoptimize_never) {
      Trace.WriteLine("This run hit the lottery!");
   }
}
```

... and changed my unit test to look like this ...

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test_ToZeroOrOne() {
   UInt64 ul;
   ul = 0UL.Deoptimize().ToZeroOrOne();
   Assert.AreEqual(0UL, ul);
   ul = 1234UL.Deoptimize().ToZeroOrOne();
   Assert.AreEqual(1UL, ul);
   AfterDeoptimize();
}
```

(that is, inserting calls to `.Deoptimize()` after literal input values and then making sure somewhere at the end is a call to `AfterDeoptimize();`).

It actually works - now when I go read the disassembly I see this ...

```
00007FFA0B9C4CF5  xor         ecx,ecx  
00007FFA0B9C4CF7  call        qword ptr [CLRStub[MethodDescPrestub]@00007FFA0BA61E28 (07FFA0BA61E28h)]  
00007FFA0B9C4CFD  mov         rdx,rax  
00007FFA0B9C4D00  neg         rdx  
00007FFA0B9C4D03  or          rdx,rax  
00007FFA0B9C4D06  shr         rdx,3Fh
```

... where the first three lines are getting the test value 0 into rax *without* the optimizer knowing it's a 0 (the call is to my silly `Deoptimize()` thing) and then the last four lines are my actual `ToZeroOrOne()` function.

Anyway. **The Question.** Is there a more rational or normal or standard way to do this? Some way to turn off the optimizer around *just a smidge* of code? At the start, I half wondered if I could write something like this ...

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test_ToZeroOrOne() {
   UInt64 ul;
   ul = unoptimized(0UL).ToZeroOrOne();
   Assert.AreEqual(0UL, ul);
   ul = unoptimized(1234UL).ToZeroOrOne();
   Assert.AreEqual(1UL, ul);
}
```

... sorta like `unchecked()` but found nothing. Quite possibly I missed something painfully obvious.

Comment: A release build optimizes and inlines quite aggressively, so this is kind of expected. But you shouldn't really need to worry about it, as the result is obviously correct.

Comment: So ignoring the big "is this in any way a reasonable thing question" I messed around with  it a bit more and found that my Deoptimize function in some cases was still too predictable to work. With it returning only the input or the input + 1, in some cases the optimizer _still_ had enough to conclude that it didn't need to do any work.  So I changed it so that now if g_dispose has (impossibly) become some crazy vast number it actually returns a random number.

Comment: Your code under test could be compiled in release mode, but there's no reason for your unit tests to also be compiled in release. That being said, this looks like one of those tests that you write now and never fail in a hundred thousand years, so not a very useful test. Testing `val != 0 ? 1 : 0` is overkill. At least overkill for stressing over it.

Comment: My ToZeroOrOne function is actually doing [ unchecked((n | (~n + 1)) >> 31) ] which I find pretty far from obvious and in need of some validation. But it's kinda satisfying in that it compiles all the way down to just 4 assembly instructions with no branches. And my actual unit test is trying a whole bunch of differently 'interesting' bit patterns to make sure it actually works. Hence my attempt to simplify the question down to the abstract "Has one ever found that Release build unit tests are too smart and remove too much code and done anything tidy to mitigate it".

Comment: If it was "too smart" then this would mean that the result of the tests would be different than in the debug build. If you can show an example of _that_ happening, then indeed there's something seriously wrong.

Comment: Perhaps it wasn't obvious but part of what I'm doing in my tests is reading the generated assembly to verify that stuff I think is going to inline and in some cases disappear entirely is actually doing so. If there were a way to add unit test Asserts of the form "Assert(this function includes no calls (or branches) when optimized)" I'd be doing that.